# How to fix issue with decimal values in Sybase ODBC driver using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, odbc, sybase, decimal

Sybase ODBC driver have an issue with the decimal data type.

For example, when an application is trying to save in the database a decimal value occurs this error:

```
ERROR [22018] [DataDirect][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'DECIMAL' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Same error occurs when you trying to pass decimal parameter to stored procedure.

How we can fix it using NHibernate or Fluent NHibernate?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC? NHibernate supports the Sybase client.

Comment: This issue affects the ADO.Net library for Sybase ASE as well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found simple solution for this. I changed in xml's and POCO's System.Decimal to System.Double and it works. I tried add own sql-insert and sql-update in xml files with CONVERT but it didn't work well (eg. value 5.15 was changed to 515).

Comment: Also switched to System.Double and it worked for me, too (note: using Sybase ASE ado.net provider).

Answer (score 0):

The Database does not support implicit conversion of char , varchar to decimal . This has the same behaviour for JDBC . Please use Convert function and the run the query .